# Log proccesses activities for later analysis

Tags: 14.04, freeze, log, crash

I'm having a problem with a *Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS* machine that occasionally freezes up for no reason that I can logically predict.

Once it happens the HDD usage seems quite high for no reason (normally I'm not using any software that "is using" the HDD), so I believe I can look for which program is doing that and uninstall it.

But I can't do anything like opening the system monitor, or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> the terminal to use `top`, `iotop` or any command, or anything like that.

So the only solution I can think of, is to log data of the processes, like HDD usage, memory usage, processor usage, to find the problem once I reset the computer and log back on ubuntu.

Does anyone know a way to do that, or have another idea for solving this problem?

EDIT: I found out today (almost 2 years later) that the problem was probably some bug with chrome's flash eating all of my ram. I was able to find out because now I have 8gb ram and 4gb swap, so once my computer started getting somewhat slow for no reason I was able to check the System Monitor, and the flash process alone was taking more than 2gb and started eating my swap. So I ended the process and disabled flash for chrome. Disabling flash isn't a problem nowadays because most of the stuff will work, like YouTube, Facebook video, Netflix, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For logging the data, you can use sysstat package from ubuntu repositories.

Install it by

```
sudo apt-get install sysstat
```

After installing you need to enable logging of data. For this, change in the file /etc/default/sysstat

```
sudo vim /etc/default/sysstat
```

from

```
ENABLED="false"
```

to

```
ENABLED="true"
```

Once everything setup, it will start logging the events like disk usage, cpu usage etc.

Use following command to know more

`man sar`

Hope this helps...